# Make VS2010 navigate to the file containing the error

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Imagine the following scenario. You receive an error while building.

[img01 http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/5975/img01g.png](http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/5975/img01g.png)

[img02 http://img339.imageshack.us/img339/7287/img02.png](http://img339.imageshack.us/img339/7287/img02.png)

[img03 http://img28.imageshack.us/img28/2051/img03.png](http://img28.imageshack.us/img28/2051/img03.png)

If I double-click on the error, nothing happens in the Solution tab i.e. I never get navigated to the file containing the error.

[img04 http://img194.imageshack.us/img194/3687/img04f.png](http://img194.imageshack.us/img194/3687/img04f.png)

Anyone got an idea how this can be achieved. It might be just me, but I find it pretty annoying.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Best Regards,

Kiril

Comment: You need four large images that will fade away in the future to illustrate such a simple point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tools > Options ... > Project and Solution > General > **Track Active Item in Solution Explorer**

Comment: Thanks, that worked. The funny thing was that "Track Active Item in Solution Explorer" was checked and it still did not work. I had to uncheck and check it again to make it work. Thanks again.